# How to get random elements from an Elixir map?

Tags: dictionary, random, elixir

I have an Elixir map:

```rb
iex(1)> my_map = %{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
%{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
```

**What can I use to get random elements from this map?**

In Python I can do this:

```py
>>> my_map = {'a': "one", 'b': "two", 'c': "three"}
>>> random.choice(list(my_map.items())) # Get 1 random key-value pair
('a', 'one')
>>> random.sample(my_map.items(), 2) # Get 2 random key-value pairs
[('b', 'two'), ('c', 'three')]
>>> random.choice(list(my_map.keys())) # Get a random key
'b'
>>> random.sample(list(my_map.keys()), 2) # Get 2 random keys
['c', 'a']
>>> random.choice(list(my_map.values())) # Get a random value
'three'
>>> random.sample(list(my_map.values()), 2) # Get 2 random values
['two', 'one']
```

**Does Elixir have similar tools to extract random elements from a map?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Get a random key-value pair

- Use [**`Enum.random(enumerable)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) to get a single random element
- Use [**`Enum.take_random(my_map, 2)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take_random/2) to get more random elements

Example:

```rb
iex(1)> my_map = %{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
%{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"} # Get 1 random key-value pair
iex(2)> Enum.random(my_map)
{:b, "two"}
iex(3)> Enum.take_random(my_map, 2) # Get 2 random key-value pairs
[b: "two", a: "one"]
```

### Get a random key

- You can use **[`Map.keys(map)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#keys/1)** to get a list of your map's keys. Then use [**`Enum.random(enumerable)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) to select a random element from this list
- You can also use [**`Enum.take_random(my_map, 2)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take_random/2) to get more random keys

Example:

```rb
iex(1)> my_map = %{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
%{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
iex(2)> my_map |> Map.keys() |> Enum.random() # Get 1 random key
:b
iex(3)> my_map |> Map.keys() |> Enum.take_random(2) # Get 2 random keys
[:a, :c]
```

***OR***

You can directly use [**`Enum.random(enumerable)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) and some [pattern matching](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html) to get a random key:

```rb
iex(1)> my_map = %{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
%{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
iex(2)> {key, _} = Enum.random(my_map)
{:c, "three"}
iex(3)> key
:c
```

### Get a random value

- You can use **[`Map.values(map)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#keys/1)** to get a list of your map's values. Then use [**`Enum.random(enumerable)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) to select a random element from this list
- You can also use [**`Enum.take_random(my_map, 2)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take_random/2) to get more random values

Example:

```rb
iex(1)> my_map = %{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
%{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
iex(2)> my_map |> Map.values() |> Enum.random() # Get 1 random value
"one"
iex(3)> my_map |> Map.values() |> Enum.take_random(2) # Get 2 random values
["one", "three"]
```

***OR***

You can directly use [**`Enum.random(enumerable)`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) and some [pattern matching](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html) to get a random value:

```rb
iex(1)> my_map = %{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
%{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
iex(2)> {_, value} = Enum.random(my_map)
{:c, "three"}
iex(3)> value
"three"
```